# What does this use of 'there' mean?

Tags: word-meaning, locative

> [Ron] "Look –– they're off Ouch!"
>        Someone had poked Ron in the back of the head. It was Malfoy. "Oh, sorry, Weasley, didn't see you **there**."
>  (Harry Potter and
>   the Sorcerer's Stone)

They say adverbs can modify the head of noun phrase, not nouns. So ‘there’ does not modify ‘you’. What does ‘there’ do: is it a predicative over ‘you’ or is it just an adverb––meaning ‘in that place’?

Comment: I don't really see what you're asking. In this context, it seems perfectly natural to understand ***there*** as modifying ***you*** ("there" = *in that place where you were*). But if you insist on calling "there" an ***adverb*** you could always think of it as modifying the verb ***to see*** *("Is that Harry Potter I see there?")*. It doesn't affect the *meaning*, however you understand it.

Comment: I was writing an answer, but I have to agree with @FumbleFingers here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, *there* can modify *you*.

As McCawley says, pronouns don't "stand for" nouns but for entire noun phrases. Consequently *you* is a noun phrase, and (by default) its own Head.

You could pick up McCawley's recategorization of adverbs as Ad-Vs, Ad-Ns, Ad-Ss, &c and say that  *there* here acts as an Ad-N´.

And if you want to sound really impressive and be really confusing, you could parallel that recategorization by saying that just as *you* is a Pro-N´, what *there* really **is** is a Pro-P´ or Pro-S, or whatever you think it stands for:

> Oh, sorry, Weasley, didn't see you ***there***.
>   Oh, sorry, Weasley, didn't see you ***in that place***.
>   Oh, sorry, Weasley, didn't see you ***standing right in front of me***.
>   Oh, sorry, Weasley, didn't see you ***blinking stupidly like the proletarian cretin you are***.
>   Oh, sorry, Weasley, didn't see you ***offering an irresistible target***.

Comment: Similarly, The OALD says that a pronoun is, "a word that is used instead of a noun or a noun phrase"; the NOAD says that a pronoun is, "a word that can function by itself as a noun phrase and that refers either to the participants in the discourse."

Comment: @StoneyB, I found that a pronoun stand for an NP in CGEL (p1462), but not at McCawley's. Would you tell me in what page is the word?

Comment: @Listenever I had to take it back to the library, but I think it's in the chapter where he talks about word classes/parts of speech.