# How to understand “there” following “on the wall”?

Tags: parsing

> It is Sunday afternoon. There are two boys in the candy shop. They are
>   looking at the candy. A clerk is cleaning the desk. There is a clock
>   **on the wall there**. It is five thirty. A sign is next to the clock. It says, “Don't drink here.” A woman and a man are taking
>   pictures in front of the beautiful shop. They are happy.
> <sub>Source: *In the Candy Shop,* Page 5 [here](http://www.docin.com/p-255980800.html)</sub>

Is “there” a postpositive attribute or an apposition of “on the wall”?

Comment: I believe that we can parse it at least two ways: a) "There, there is a clock on the wall." b) "A wall is there. There is a clock on it." Both alternatives, though a little different from each other, are very similar in meaning, and can be used to describe exactly the same scene. If you chose to parse it as in b), I agree that the "there" there would be a post-positive attribute of "the wall". For more formal analyses, please wait for other answerers.

Comment: your link is bad. it keeps on loading and nothing loads for a long time.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/8182/3281

Answer (score 1):

I've spoken English all my life but the sentence *Is “there” a postpositive attribute or an apposition of “on the wall”?* is French to me.

Hell, let's break down the sentence and build it:

> There is a clock.

To say 'there is', as we know, only means that in the space you've defined, you may find a clock. So, let's place the clock:

> There is a clock on the wall.

This narrows down the possible locations of the clock, but, without context, this wall could be anywhere. Because we're currently talking about a *candy shop*, I'll assume the sentence means:

> There is a clock on the wall in the candy shop.

English has a nice way of avoiding the need to mention a place twice. A candy shop is a 'place' and a place is later referred to as 'here' or '**there**'.

> There is a clock on the wall **there**.

I haven't the foggiest idea how this relates to your question, but I'm hoping this'll clear it up.

Comment: "I've spoken English all my life" - hyperbole or prodigy?

Comment: Isn't all of language hyperbole? :)